How to consume a remote web api in IIS server with an android maui application
I have created a web api and installed it into a web server under iis. I used it with a windows maui application and all is OK. I cannot consume the web api with the maui android app .
As usual I use
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var BaseUrl = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android
    ? "http://10.0.2.2:5257"
    : "http://api_test:5257";
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{BaseUrl}/api/Cds");
var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


This config (10.0.2.2) works fine with a local web api but not with remote
I have tried to replace the 10.0.2.2 with the iis web server, or allow all ip. Nothing runs OK.
as the ip 10.0.2.2 is mandatory,I would like to know how to  route the http command from 10.0.2.2 to the iis web server.

what does "Nothing runs OK" mean?  Are you getting an error or exception?  Do you get an HTTP Response code?  Does it timeout?  Are you running on a physical device, or an emulator?  If emulator, is it running on the same machine as the service?

Hi Jason, I am using the samsung emulator in vs 2022. When I say nothing runs ok , I mean that nothing happen. when debugging the program, it goes directly at the end with no error, no message .  From the line var response = await ht... it goes directly to the }.

The main question is : As the android emulator uses mandatory 10.0.2.2 ip address (its local interface) how to route its http request to the outside (the iis server) ?

this config works fine with local web api, I mean the creation of a web api, and the http clients as 2 programs in the same vs 2022 project. I do not know how to proceed with external web api (in the iis server) and maybe name resolution problem.
